# Remove specific string from url

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I made a dynamic select boxes on my wordpress page to select categories and subcategories.

The output url should be http://myurl.com/category/maincategory/subcategory 
but the form gives http://myurl.com/category/maincategory/?xy=maincategory+subcategory.

I think the easiest solution would be if a jQuery script would remove that specific part between "?" and "+" from the live URL, but i don't know how.

It'll be a hostel finder, here is the full code. Some of the script is for the dynamic select box width.

```
<form method="get" action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>">
<fieldset>
I'd like to find a nice hostel in
<select name="category_name" id="orszag" style="width: auto;">
<option value="hostels">any country</option>
<?php
// generate list of categories
$categories = get_categories('hide_empty=1&style=none&parent=2');
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    echo '<option value="', $category->slug, '">', $category->name, "</option>\n";
}
?>
</select>
, 


<select class="calc_dropdown calclinkone" id="varos" name="varos" style="width: auto;">

<option value="hostels ">any city</option>  


<option value="hungary ">any city</option>           
      <?php
// generate list of categories
$categories = get_categories('child_of=3&hide_empty=0');
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    echo '<option value="hungary ', $category->slug, '">', $category->name, "</option>\n";
}
?>





<option value="uk ">any city</option>           
      <?php
// generate list of categories
$categories = get_categories('child_of=6&hide_empty=0');
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    echo '<option value="uk ', $category->slug, '">', $category->name, "</option>\n";
}
?>






<option value="slovakia ">any city</option>           
      <?php
// generate list of categories
$categories = get_categories('child_of=17&hide_empty=0');
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    echo '<option value="slovakia ', $category->slug, '">', $category->name, "</option>\n";
}
?>




<option value="germany ">any city</option>           
      <?php
// generate list of categories
$categories = get_categories('child_of=4&hide_empty=0');
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    echo '<option value="germany ', $category->slug, '">', $category->name, "</option>\n";
}
?>

</select>





<br>
for 
<select>
<option value="">1</option>
<option value="">2</option>
<option value="">3</option>
<option value="">4</option>
<option value="">5</option>
<option value="">6</option>
</select>
person for
<select>
<option value="">1</option>
<option value="">2</option>
<option value="">3</option>
<option value="">4</option>
<option value="">5</option>
<option value="">6</option>
</select> nights.<br>
<button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> Search</button>
</fieldset>
</form>


<script>

$("#orszag").change(function() { 
if($(this).data('options') == undefined){
    $(this).data('options',$('#varos option').clone());
    } 
var id = $(this).val();
var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[value*=' + id + ']');
$('#varos').html(options);
});


$('select').change(function() {
    var $opt = $(this).find("option:selected");
    var $span = $('<span>').addClass('tester').text($opt.text());

    $span.css({
        'font-family': $opt.css('font-family'),
        'font-style': $opt.css('font-style'),
        'font-weight': $opt.css('font-weight'),
        'font-size': $opt.css('font-size')
    });

    $('body').append($span);
    // The 30px is for select open icon - it may vary a little per-browser
    $(this).width($span.width() + 10);
    $span.remove();
});

$('select').change();

</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Could you paste some code?

Comment: You're sure wordpress isn't adding that for a reason? If not, parse the string and remove the `search` part.

Answer (score 1):

Use JQuery's replace method

```
  var mystring = "hellothis";
    var m = mystring.replace("this", "that");
    alert(m);
```

will produce "hellothat"

```
var myUrl = "http://myurl.com/category/maincategory/?xy=maincategory+subcategory"
var newURL = myUrl.replace("?xy=maincategory+","");
```

should give you what you want

Answer (score 0):

Here I am right now.
I have this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if(window.location.href.indexOf("?") > -1) {
       location.href=location.href.replace("?varos=germany+", "");
    }
});
```

The code is working well if i'm on Germany. Now I have to change the `?varos=germany+` part to something that defines the dynamic part of the string between ? and + and removes it.